# Can't continously read/monitor remote file

Tags: java, sftp, jsch

I'm using JSCH to try and read a log file on a separate server that is constantly being updated. I can pick up whatever is currently in the file just fine, but once I get to the end of the file my delay occurs but no new lines get picked up and my delay print statements continue to loop (I verify by running a tail on the log alongside my program). I'd appreciate it if anybody could point out something in my code that might be wrong or missing, or possibly suggest a better approach.

```
InputStream stream = sftpClient.get(filename);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
String line;
while (true)
{
    try
    {
        line = br.readLine();
        if (line == null)
        {
            System.out.println("End of file reached. Sleeping..");
            Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
            System.out.println("Retrying for more data..");
        }
        else
        {
            //do something with line, print for now.
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Something went wrong: " + e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see source code for Jsch's `ChannelSftp` [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.jcraft/jsch/0.1.51/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.java). The [InputStream returned by jsch](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.jcraft/jsch/0.1.51/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.java#1320) when you get a remote file sets a flag when you read to the end of the remote file. Continuing to try to read from the stream will just return the cached EOF indication.

Jsch has [a `stat()` method to retrieve information about a remote file](http://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.html#stat(java.lang.String)), including its size and last-modified timestamp. Jsch also has [a version of the get method](http://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.html#get(java.lang.String,%20com.jcraft.jsch.SftpProgressMonitor,%20long)) which lets you skip over the first part of the remote file. You could periodically call stat() to detect whether the file has changed, then use get() to skip over the part of the file which you've already read and just read the new content.

You may also want to consider using a different SSH client library. The [SFTP protocol](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-secsh-filexfer-02) contains low-level commands to open a remote file and read or write arbitrary sections of the file. Jsch, however, doesn't expose the full range of this functionality through ChannelSftp. There are other java SFTP client libraries which provides lower-level access to the SFTP protocol.

Comment: I figured I'd have to go the file size checking route, thanks for all the info.!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should re-open the file when end is reached.
If it is for production purpose, try using Apache tailer
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/Tailer.html

Answer (score 0):

Just to add on what crv has mentioned, here is an example on how you can use Apache `Tailor`

```
import java.io.File;

import org.apache.commons.io.input.Tailer;
import org.apache.commons.io.input.TailerListener;
import org.apache.commons.io.input.TailerListenerAdapter;

public class FileTailor {

    private static final int SLEEP = 500;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        FileTailor fileTailor = new FileTailor();
        fileTailor.run("log_file.log");
    }

    private void run(String path) throws InterruptedException {
        TailerListener listener = new LogFileListener();
        Tailer tailer = Tailer.create(new File(path), listener, SLEEP);
        tailer.run();
    }

    public class LogFileListener extends TailerListenerAdapter {
        @Override
        public void handle(String line) {
            //do something with line, print for now.
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't likely to work for a file on a remote system, accessed through SFTP.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying this, in my case, I have to read a log continuously, but I can only access it by sftp, as @Kenster mentions, I check if the file has changed in size by calling `stat()` and then use the `get( String src, String dst, SftpProgressMonitor monitor, int mode)`, what it does is generate a new file in my directory and with the mode parameter in `RESUME`, it only takes the latest content.

```java
long remotepointer = 0;
SftpATTRS atrr = null;
Strinf remoteFile = "log.txt"
Strinf tempFile = "/tmp/data/log.txt"
while (true){
    try {  
      atrr =  channelSftp.stat(remoteFile);
      if(atrr.getSize() > remotepointer){
        remotepointer = atrr.getSize();
        channelSftp.get(remoteFile, tempFile,null,ChannelSftp.RESUME);
      }
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Something went wrong: " + e);
    }
}
```